# Where is UISplitViewController in universal App?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, universal

I made an application for the iPhone and now I want to make a port for the iPad. So I changed the setting to Universal. I would like to use for the iPad version the Split View, but I do not see it anywhere (I use Storyboard). Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you switch the app to universal you have to create a separate iPad storyboard.  Goto New File and under User Interface choose storyboard.  When you click next it will ask you device family, choose iPad.  After you create the storyboard and go there you will see the Split View Controller as in @Aaron Brager answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the object library in the lower-right corner:

[image]

Comment: (Image from http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial)